# How do I specify the --form field in Ruby code (for an HTTP GET request)?

Tags: ruby, curl, sinatra

I know that in a curl command, there is an option to specify a --form like this:

```
-F 'ns=com.my-organization.canvas-app'
```

I want to know how I can convert this to Ruby code when making an HTTP GET request.

I've managed to figure out how to specify the --data field in Ruby code. So if the --data field of a curl command looks like this:

```
-d property1=value1 -d property2=value2
```

Then the data field in the corresponding Ruby code should look something like this:

```
data = {property1: "value1", property2: "value2"}
```

But now I'm trying to understand how I can convert this:

```
-F 'ns=com.my-organization.canvas-app'
```

into the corresponding Ruby code.

I'm also using HTTParty for the HTTP requests.

As of now, this is the code I have for the GET request:

```
form={ns: "com.my-organization.canvas-app"}

getResponse = HTTParty.get(base_url,:body => form.json, :headers => $header)
puts getResponse.body
```

As you can see, I specified the --form in a variable called "form" and used it as an argument to the HTTParty.get() call. Am I doing this correctly?